# Ajax does not display data from database when 'reply comment' button is clicked on

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am developing a post/reply comment system. The post sends and displays data from database using Ajax, jquery and Php.

The Ajax for inserting and displaying a post from the database works well. The Ajax for inserting a comment/reply into the database also works well, But the ajax for displaying the comment/reply to those post does not work.

When i reply a post, is does not display immediately as it should except i refresh the page, that is when i will see the comment/reply text.

```
//where post retrieved from database displays.

<div class="panelchat panel" id="postRows"></div>
```

```
// Ajax for inserting and displaying post.

 $("#post-form-id").on('submit', (function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();     

    $.ajax({
    url: "forumAjax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:  new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(data) {
    $("#post-form-id")[0].reset(); 
    $("#previewImg").hide();
    }       
    });
    displayPost();
    $("#post-form-id")[0].reset(); 


 }));


function displayPost() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "forumAjax.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: {
        "postDisplay" : 1
        }, 
        success: function(data) {

        $("#postRows").html(data);
        oneClickFunc();
        }
    });     
    replyFunc();
}
displayPost();



function oneClickFunc() {

        $("label.replyText").one("click", function() {

        var comCode = $(this).attr("name");
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        parent.append("<br /><form action='' method='POST' id='replyForm'><a href='#' class='imgLink'><img src='resources/images/why5.png' class='reply-image' /></a><textarea class='reply-textarea' name='replyTextarea' id='commentReply' autocorrect='on' spellcheck='spellcheck' maxlength='500' placeholder='Write a reply...'></textarea><input type='hidden' name='code' value='"+comCode+"' /><input type='submit' class='form-submit' id='replyBtn' name='ReplyBtn' value='Send' /></form><br />");

        autosize(document.getElementById("commentReply"));

        replyFunc();        
    });

}



function replyFunc() {

        $("#replyForm").on('submit', (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
        url: "forumAjax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#replyForm")[0].reset(); 
        }     
        });
        postReplyDisplay();
    }));


    }

replyFunc();


function postReplyDisplay() {

    $.ajax({
    url: "forumAjax.php",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: {
        "newReplyx" : 1
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }, 
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errordata) {
        alert(errordata);
    }
}); 
}
postReplyDisplay();
```

```
//Php code that inserts and retrieves data from database.

if(!empty($_POST['replyTextarea'])) {


    $userReply = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['replyTextarea']);
    $userID = $mysqli->escape_string($_SESSION['user_id']);
    $replyDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $replyCode = $_POST['code'];

    $INSERT = "INSERT INTO forumreply (reply, replyDate, codeMatch) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($INSERT);
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $userReply, $replyDate, $replyCode);
    $stmt->execute();

}



if(isset($_POST["postDisplay"])) {

    $email = $mysqli->escape_string($_SESSION['email']);

    $result = "SELECT * FROM forum ORDER BY user_id DESC";
    $Chatresult = $mysqli->query($result);

    if($Chatresult->num_rows > 0) {

        while($rows = $Chatresult->fetch_assoc()) {

            $image = $rows["image"];
            $postContent = $rows["post"];
            $datePosted = new dateTime($rows["postDate"]);
            $datePosted = date_format($datePosted, 'M j, Y | H:i:s');
            $postCode = $rows['code'];

                echo '<br /><div id="'.$postCode.'" class="postSeparator">';
                    echo '<a href="#"><img src="resources/images/passport1.jpg" title="CLEAN WATER" class="q-pic"></a>';
                    echo '<span class="name"><a href="#">Mariela Collazo</a></span>';
                    echo '<span class="postDate">'.$datePosted.'</span>';

                    if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) != 1) {
                    echo '';
                    } else {
                    echo '<span class="add-user edit-post"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><ul class="editPost"><li>Edit post</li><li>Delete &nbsp;<i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></li><li>Report post <i class="far fa-flag"></i></li></ul>
                    </span>'.'<span id="addUser" class="add-user"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>&nbsp;<span class="text">Follow</span>
                    </span>';
                    }

if($image === "") { echo "";
} 
else { echo '<a href="resources/images/forum/'.$image.'" target="_blank"><img src="resources/images/forum/'.$image.'" alt="" class="post-picture"></a>';
                        }

if($postContent !== '') {
echo '<textarea class="post" readonly="true" id="#" autocorrect="off">'.stripslashes($postContent).'</textarea>';
} else {echo '';
}

echo '<div class="activity-wrapper" id="'.$postCode.'">';

echo '<label class="replyText" name="'.$postCode.'"><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reply</label>|
                        <span class="thumbsUp" title="Like"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>&nbsp;<span class="reply-counter">7</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="times"><i class="fas fa-times" title="Dislike"></i>&nbsp;<span class="reply-counter">3</span></span> <br />';


$result = "SELECT * FROM forumreply WHERE codeMatch = '$postCode' ORDER BY replyDate DESC";
                $replyResult = $mysqli->query($result);
                $childContent = $replyResult->num_rows;


                if($childContent == 0) {
                    echo '<label class="commentLabel" name="'.$postCode.'">Comments (<span class="reply-counter">'.$childContent.'</span>) </label><br />';

                } else {

                    echo '<label class="commentLabel" name="'.$postCode.'">Comments (<span class="reply-counter">'.$childContent.'</span>) </label><br />';
                    echo '</div><br />'; 


echo '<div id="child-comments" id="C-'.$postCode.'">';

    foreach($replyResult as $com) {
                        $childDate = new dateTime($com['replyDate']);
                        $childDate = date_format($childDate, 'M j, Y | H:i:s');
                        $chiCom = $com['reply'];



echo '<div class="child postReplyx" id="'.$postCode.'-C">'
                                .'<a href="#"><img src="resources/images/passport1.jpg" class="userPic"></a>'
                                .'<span class="time">'.$childDate.'</span>'
                                .'<span class="options"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i><ul class="actions"><li>Edit reply</li><li>Delete &nbsp;<i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></li></ul></span>'
                                .'<div class="comment-text">'.stripslashes($chiCom).'</div>'.'<div id="emoji-options"><span class="fontAwesome" title="Like"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i><span class="counter">4</span></span><span class="fontAwesome" title="Dislike"><i class="fas fa-times"></i><span class="counter">4</span></span></div>'
                            .'</div>';

                    }

                    echo '</div>'; 

                } 


                        echo '</div>';  

        echo '</div>';


     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the postReplyDisplay() function too soon. Remember ajax is asynchronous meaning it goes away to do its job while the script keeps running. you are displaying results while ajax is not done updating. move the postReplyDisplay() inside the success of replyFunc().

```
function replyFunc() {

        $("#replyForm").on('submit', (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
           url: "forumAjax.php",
           type: "POST",
           data:  new FormData(this),
           contentType: false,
           cache: false,
           processData:false,
           success: function(data) {
              $("#replyForm")[0].reset();
              postReplyDisplay(); 
           }     
        });        
    }));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response Nawed Khan. I have done that yet the reply text does not display immediately unless the page is refreshed.